# Array is not displayed in a list correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I´m facing a problem with displaying my Array in a list.

The Response of my Ajax-Request does look like this:

```
[{"id":"1","counter":"1"},{"id":"2","counter":"2"},{"id":"3","counter":"3"}]
```

My Action Code:

```
export default function getItems(){
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch (fecthItem())
    }
 }

 function fecthItem(){
    return dispatch => {
      // dispatch(requestPost())
       return fetch('http://localhost:444/localWebServices/getCounter.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(json)))
     }
  }

 function receivePosts(json){
   console.log("receivePosts");
   var items = [];
   console.log(json.map( x => x.counter))
   // var items = json.map( x => x.counter);
   for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(json[i].counter);
        items.push(json[i].counter)
    }

     return {
       type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS',
       items: items
     }
   }
```

My Reducer  - getItem:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case 'RECEIVE_POSTS':
        return [
                ...state,
                {
                    text: action.items
                }
            ]
    default:
        return state

   }
 }
```

Currently the result is displayed, but I´m not able to display each in an 
own row of the list.

The render to code to display the result:

```
      <ul>
                {this.props.items.map((items, i) => <li key={i}>{items.text}   </li>)}
            </ul>
```

Can someone tell me what I have to change to display that items correctly in a List?

UPDATE:

Here is an Img from my Dev Console. I guess I´m creating the array the wrong way, what you think?

[image: Array]

And Here is my entire Component, that should render the list, maybe it helps :)

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


 export default class TodoList extends Component {

  render() {
    const posts = this.props.todos
    console.log(this.props.items)
    const items = this.props.items
    const isEmpty = posts.length === 0
    return (

        <div>
            <h3>Meine Aufgaben</h3>
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map((items, i) => <li key={i}>{items.text}</li>)}
            </ul>
            <ul>

                {isEmpty
                    ? <h3>Sie haben noch keinen Todo´s angelegt</h3>
                    : <h3>Ihre Ergebnisse</h3>
                }
                {this.props.todos.map((todo, i) => <li key={i}>{todo.text}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
        )
     }
   }
   const mapStateToProp = state => ({todos: state.addItem, items: state.getItem})

    export default connect (mapStateToProp)(TodoList)
```

And Here is the output of the React extension:

[image: React Extension]

UPDATE:

Okay. I guess the Error is something really basic, because as I try this with a an given Index, the item is displayed correctly:

```
  {this.props.items.map((items) => <li key={items.text}>{items.text[0]}</li>)}
```

So how can I run over that?

Comment: It's not really clear if the problem is a logic issue or a display issue. Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: it must be a logical issue i guess. I think I building the array after fetching from API the wrong way. Give me one min to append an img of my Array from dev console

Comment: Can you share the store code that deals with RECEIVE_POSTS? Are you logging the items var in props before rendering?

Comment: the Store Code and all other code can be found in my Previous Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652423/can%C2%B4t-access-props-after-using-combinereducer. The Code below where the CombineReducer is inlcuded.

Comment: @BayLife in neither of your questions do you include your implementation of getItem which (since it populates your items variable which seems to be malformed), is very likely to be the source of the issue.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or plnkr

Comment: Is it in general wrong to take an array and push that array in the Reducer?  I´m wondering, because the data are available, but in a wrong array structure. And also they are accessible as you can see in the last update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return object instead of array in your reducer

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'RECEIVE_POSTS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                items: action.items
            });
            //return {
            //    ...state,
            //    items: action.items
            //}

        default:
            return state
        }
 }
```

then you can render your items via

```
{ this.props.items.items && this.props.items.items.length &&
  this.props.items.items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item}</li>)}
```

Comment: you need to enable  transform-object-rest-spread on ur babel or set to stage 2 or above with es2015 babel feature. I had updated my answer without using spread method.

Comment: I´ve also tried to do it this way. The Syntax error is gone. But while render the .map() function throws now an error: "bundle.js:29631 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.items.map is not a function(…)"

Comment: oops, it seems like you map state to props named items, so you need to access it via this.props.items.items in this case

Comment: If I .log() this, items.items works correct. But when trying to map this "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Comment: your this.props.items.items maybe null due to items not yet been fetch, add a checking to only render if items fetched, check out my updated answer

Comment: Okay. Finally, this seems to work the result is displayed. But is this the normal way of displaying JSON-Response in component?

Comment: yes :), you can also consider some improvement such as render loading indicator when items is fetching

Comment: you should open a new question instead of asking in comments here.

Answer (score 0):

render a list of items code shall look like this:

```
 <ul>
  {this.props.items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item}   </li>)}
 </ul>
```

items.text is undefined that why you get empty list

Comment: but items.text isn´t undefined and my list isn´t empty as you can see in the last img I append to the Q. It is just not correctly displayed as list

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after several hours I found a solution for my Problem. But to say it clear, I´m not happy with that!

I hope someone can explain me how to simplify the array generating process, which occurs while passing the data from Action to reducer (I guess).

Currently I double map the array in my Render component, but this can´t be the right way of doing things. So guys If you know how to prevent that, it would be lovely if you response here.

```
  {this.props.items.map((item, i) => item.text.map((text, i) => <li key={i}>{item.text[i]}</li>))}
```

This works for now!